# Lubuntu Booting from pen drive

Tags: boot

EEE PC Asus 101CH Failed Hard drive I am using Lubuntu on a pen drive. How do I make this system boot up every time from pendrive. I have to press esc or F2 to change boot order every time. Setup in F2 does not hold settings to boot from Lubuntu.
Advice please and I like Lubuntu.

Comment: Is in the F2-menu a USB pendrive or something similiar? Because the BIOS does handle devices with their origin name.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the BIOS, and change the boot order to boot from the USB pen drive.  See image below.

**Note**: Image is for instructional purposes only, your actual options maybe different.

Once done press <kbd>F10</kbd> to save and exit.

Press F10, then Enter to confirm. The netbook will reboot.

**If you still can't boot from the USB, You may have to disable Boot Booster in the Boot section.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have done this and then it will boot up just once. I Shutdown netbook and next boot it tries to boot from failed hard drive or I get this message:Reboot and Select proper Boot device or insert Boot Media and press a key

Comment: See addition in the answer about Boot Booster.

Comment: Bios update complete. Sorry still same problem ie Reboot and Select etc

Comment: Did you check the Boot Booster?

Comment: yes and disabled that